# Caching a specific file (e.g. by setting HTTP headers for it) in lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd

Hey Stackoverflow people,

In lighttpd, I want to set specific HTTP headers for a specific file (not site wide).

Basically I don't want to cache the main index.html file.

One catch, I can't add any new modules to lighttpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add new modules, but have not shared which modules are available in your limited environment.  This is not a well written question.

If you are unable to use mod_expire in lighttpd, then I would suggest using meta http-equiv tags in the index.html to limit caching.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModExpire

http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_pragma